# Exception while connecting with Chrome driver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, cucumber

How to use Chrome Driver in selenium project? Here am using latest version of Chrome Driver. My code looks like:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", C:\\Users\\....\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32_2.3.zip\\chromedriver.exe");
```

In 64 bit Windows 7, however I am getting an exception.

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to
>   discover open pages

I searched in google they provide the solution to replace the latest version of Chrome driver. I tried but not able to solve the issue.

Comment: You have version 2.3 of the ChromeDriver, so what version of Chrome are you running? Also unzip the folder so it can be accessed properly.

Answer (score 1):

`chromedriver_win32` supports both 32-bit and 64-bit machines.

Use the latest chromedriver version; Download it from,

> http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.9/

And add the below snippet in your code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");    
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you unzip **chromedriver_win32_2.3.zip** file and then provide location of ChromeDriver inside unzipped folder ... This should help. Modified code should look like the following:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Users\....\Downloads\chromedriver_win32_2.3\chromedriver.exe");
```